# Rigid curves and reducibility

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

On a projective complex surface, a curve $C$ may sit in a linear equivalence class $[C]$ that is given as a sum $[C] = [C_1] + [C_2]$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are effective. In general the curves in the class $[C]$ are not necessarily all reducible, though they may be: for example, there are both reducible and irreducible curves in the class $[H]+[H]$ on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ where $[H]$ is the hyperplane class.

Now further suppose that $[C_1]^2 < 0$ (EDIT: and that $C_1$ is irreducible), implying that $C_1$ is the only curve in its linear equivalence class. Is it now the case that  every curve in the class $[C] = [C_1] + [C_2]$ is reducible with one component given by $C_1$? Or, if not, are there further restrictions on $[C_1]$ and $[C_2]$ that do force this to be true?

Comment: First, unless you assume that $C_1$ is irreducible, in general $C_1^2<0$ does not imply that $C_1$ is the only curve in its equivalence class. Even with that assumption, the second statement is rarely true. One condition which will easily imply it of course is $C_1\cdot C<0$.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks very much for your comment. I should have specified $C_1$ to be irreducible, thank you. Also, I would be very interested in an understanding of the last implication you mention. If you would make an answer addressing that I will happily accept it.

Comment: If $C$ is linearly equivalent to an effective divisor $\sum a_i D_i$ with $a_i>0$ and $D_i$ irreducible, we see that $C_1\cdot D_i<0$ for some $i$ if you assume $C_1\cdot C<0$. Since both $C_1, D_i$ are irreducible, the only way this can happen is if $C_1=D_i$, which is what you want to prove.